# Sending Special Code to Linux Server Via a Button on the Browser

Tags: php, linux, http, web

We are currently sending Linux commands that go to the database through HTTP protocol, and from the Web server, the commands are sent to a remote Linux server through telnet protocol(connection). The response of the request to the remote server is displayed in an output window on the browser.

We have already achieved the above task, but we still want to have two buttons: 'Abort' and 'Reboot' on the browser(gui) that will send request to the browser, and then to the remote Linux server, and the response displayed in an output window on the browser.

Presently, we have the following code snippet:

```
<input type="button" name="Abort" onclick="send_cmd(this.form, true)" />
<input type="button" name="Reboot" onclick="send_cmd(this.form, true)" />



function send_cmd(frm, kCmd)
{
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
            console.log("remote:"+xmlhttp.responseText);
            if(xmlhttp.responseText.indexOf("Permission denied") > -1) {
                alert("Permission denied. Please ask administrator for next available time slots.");
            }
        }
    }

    if(kCmd){
        cmd= "";    //empty for now
    }
    else{
        cmd=frm.command.value;
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","cmd_request.php?q="+cmd,true);
    xmlhttp.send();

    setTimeout(function(){window.location.href="cmd.php"}, 1000);
}
```

Will appreciate any idea on how to make this work. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a background service on your web service, and this service can execute your linux commands, return the execute result or other thing, like:

```
<?php
$ret = exec("su -c /path/to/command -s /bin/bash -l otheruser", $out, $err);
var_dump($ret);
var_dump($out);
var_dump($err);
?>
```

Document: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php

Comment: Hi Chengpohi, thanks so much for your answer to my question. We will review your idea and the attached source. We will let you know if it works.

Comment: presently, we have the following on the browser where we can send Linux commands to database and get instant response on the output window. The task is to add same functionality to a button element, say, "Ctr+ C" or "Abort", etc, to achieve same result.